# user connections in django

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create a django website that has some social networking features. Users should be able to connect to one another. The models that I have created look like this:

```
class Jumper(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def connections(self):
        jumpers = []
        for connection in self.connection_set.all():
            if connection.jumper_1.id == self.id:
                jumpers += connection.jumper_2
            else:
                jumpers += connection.jumper_1

        return jumpers


class Connection(models.Model):
    """
    A connection between two jumpers
    """

    # the jumpers to connect
    jumper_1 = models.ForeignKey(Jumper, related_name='connection_jumper_1')
    jumper_2 = models.ForeignKey(Jumper, related_name='connection_jumper_2')

    # confirmed, yes or no
    confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

This doesn't work, as `Jumper.connection_set` is undefined. I tried printing out the fields:

```
>>> print([i for i in self.__dir__() if '_set' in i])
['jump_set', '_set_pk_val', 'equipment_set', '__setattr__']
```

but there don't appear to be any connection-related things. Am I missing something, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You've overridden the reverse accessors by declaring `related_name` attributes: you need to use them instead.

However, what you actually want is a ManyToManyField pointing at 'self' - call it `connections`, then you can drop the Connection class altogether, and replace the existing propery with just `self.connections.all()`.

Comment: how could I keep the confirmation of each relationship like I have in this model with a `ManyToManyField`?